Unable to install avatar2 on windows
I'm trying to install the avatar2 package, but I'm encountering this error:
posix_ipc_module.c(37): fatal error C1083: Non è possibile aprire il file inclusione: 'sys/time.h': No such file or directory

I know that it is needed a unix system, bu the framework i'm trying to implement works with angr, which could work also in Windows. Are there any way to install this package on Windows?

Although not explicitly stated, this package doesn't seem to support Windows as can be seen in the installation instructions provided on their GitHub which uses POSIX style commands.
One way you can use this package on Windows is to install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which provides a compatibility layer that lets you run Linux binary executables natively on Windows. You can build your project using WSL on your Windows machine and install packages in your Linux environment (don't forget to use virtual environments).
See How to install Linux on Windows with WSL.
